# Java tcp socket conversion to udp

Tags: java, sockets, udp

Currently I have my tcp version of the socket in this form.

```
final ServerSocket serverSocketConn = new ServerSocket(9000);               
               while (true) 
                    {
                        try
                        {
                                Socket socketConn1 = serverSocketConn.accept();
                                new Thread(new ConnectionHandler(socketConn1)).start();                     
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            System.out.println("MyError:Socket Accepting has been caught in main loop."+e.toString());
                            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
                        }
                    }
class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable {

    private Socket receivedSocketConn1;
    ConnectionHandler(Socket receivedSocketConn1) {
      this.receivedSocketConn1=receivedSocketConn1;
    }

     try{
          BufferedWriter bWriter =  new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(receivedSocketConn1.getOutputStream()));
         BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(receivedSocketConn1.getInputStream()));

     }

}
```

It works fine so I am in the midst of converting it into UDP.

```
public class commUDP9000 {
  class ReceiverThread implements Runnable {
    private DatagramSocket  receivedSocketConn1;
    ReceiverThread(DatagramSocket  receivedSocketConn1) {
      System.out.println("Thread Received");
      this.receivedSocketConn1=receivedSocketConn1;
    }
    public void run(){
        while (true){
            try{
                    //                      
             final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
             final DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
             receivedSocketConn1.receive(receivePacket);
             String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData());                   
             System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);   
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("MyError:Socket Accepting has been caught in main loop."+e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace(System.out);
            }
        }
     }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       new commUDP9000();
   }
   commUDP9000() {     
      try{
               final DatagramSocket  serverSocketConn = new DatagramSocket (9000);
               new Thread(new ReceiverThread(serverSocketConn)).start();                            

      } 
      catch (Exception e) 
      {
         System.out.println("MyError:Socket Conn has been caught in main loop."+e.toString());
         e.printStackTrace(System.out);
         //System.exit(0); 
      }
   }
}
```

I run this and end up with

MyError:Socket Accepting has been caught in main loop.java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create connections on UDP since it is connectionless.

```
DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);

DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
```

Only send and receive are allowed here.

with UDP, what you can do is, send one single packet to the other end. if you have sequence of packets, they are treated as individual packets. the delivery is not guaranteed. the limit of payload per message is around 64kbites. in theory but depends on ur network MTU (probably 1500bytes). the only benefit is its fast and overhead is minimum.

So you should create a enough buffer early. If you want to emulate a stream, you have to implement your own protocol on top of Datagram. the same way, connection oriented TCP implemented on top of connectionless IP protocol.

Comment: @So I have emulate this now  final DatagramSocket  serverSocketConn = new DatagramSocket (9000);    
      while (true) 
     {
      try 
      {
                 new Thread(new ConnectionHandler(serverSocketConn)).start();               
      }
     {
      try 
      {
                // Socket socketConn1 = serverSocketConn.accept();
                                new Thread(new ConnectionHandler(serverSocketConn)).start();               
      }

Comment: This is an example usage of udp.http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/
Yes you have to emulate.

Comment: I must set the buffer size in advance ? IS there any no way like how I am doing in tcp where I have this  BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(receivedSocketConn1.getInputStream())); then I do this while ((nextChar=bReader.read()) != -1)

Comment: @The received packet will will then be a full packet which is sent so I guess I need to modify by my own the extraction of it. So maybe I can play with sub string to extract rather then doing the !=-1 ?

Comment: Use String output = new String(receivedByteArray);

Comment: But according to the e.g. is this String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData()); so how you convert it ? In tcp while ((nextChar=bReader .read()) != -1) and once it hit the !=-1 it will end the connection can I emulate that here ?

Comment: when you say receivePacket.getData it gives all the data as an array. normally if you have 1000 byte buffer and you have 20 characters, the 21st character is \0 which indicates the end of the string. Here using String output = new String(byteArray) we have just converted the bytes to string. now you have your whole message as one single string. Do whatever you want using this string.

Comment: can you see my question I have updated my latest codes and end up with this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread. I am trying to simulate the multi thread ?

Comment: The whole concept **ConnectionHandler** is wrong since no connection to handle. You have to rethink. with datagrams, you can receive, you can send.
In your code, you are just creating threads in an infinite loop. Thats why OutOfMemory.

Comment: ok I have updated my question again now where in the while loop I just run everything and not calling the connectionhandler. But in this case I end up with this error loop.java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Comment: Hay dude, Editing the question like this is not good at all in stackoverflow, because when other person go through this, he'll see that answers are not relevant to the question.

Comment: Create your Socket only once program. pass it into the thread you create. your while(true) receive call should be in the run() method.

Comment: Sorry for my multiple changes on the question. So you suggest to create the socket here meaning this  final DatagramSocket  serverSocketConn = new DatagramSocket (9000);? Which thread I should pass it to ? Is this how I pass new Thread(new ConnectionHandler(serverSocketConn)).start(); ?

Comment: Yes, then pass it to your ConnectionHandler class. rename that connection handler to ReceiverThread to make it more meaningful.in that class run method, have while(true) loop. inside that while(true), call socket.receive(...

Comment: sorry I have again updated my question with latest codes yet I am getting the same error of MyError:Socket Accepting has been caught in main loop.java.net.BindException: Address already in use. I am doing the socket receive in the while(true) in public void run()?

Comment: There is another process using the port 9000. Please kill that process. first before you run this.

Comment: ok now all runs find and I have put my full codes. Normally for tcp I do this telent ip 9000 to test if my server is fine. In this case I cant make any connection to the server and and it it just show this when I start System.out.println("Thread Received");

Answer (score 1):

You're just creating endless threads that all just receive from the same socket. You only need one of those, and the loop should be inside its run() method.

Comment: can you suggest how to do it cause I end up with memory exception.

Comment: @user2711681 I just did 'suggest how to do it'. One thread, with a read loop inside it. What part of that don't you understand?

Comment: based on your suggestion I have updated my question where first I call this final DatagramSocket  serverSocketConn = new DatagramSocket (9000);
               new Thread(new ReceiverThread(serverSocketConn)).start(); then I all the process is in done the public void run() with while loop in it. Still I get this error "MyError:Socket Conn has been caught in main loop.java.net.BindException: Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use"

Comment: You do realize that's a new problem, don't you? Caused by the old code still running? or creating the `DatagramSocket` in a loop?

Comment: Is is cause by the while loop kind of lost here not too sure with the process ? Any hint ?

Comment: What while loop? If you're creating DatagramSockets inside a loop, *don't.*

Comment: I just receiving the packet final DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
             receivedSocketConn1.receive(receivePacket); ? I am creating the DatagramSocket in the main function pass the thread and then just refer it in the while loop ?

Comment: Come off it. How am I suppose to make any sense of that? Post your current code. By which I mean edit it into your question.

Comment: I have updated my question with the full codes labelled as commUDP9000

Comment: So, as the message says, there is already something else bound to UDP port 9000: most probably, as I said above, a prior instance of your program. Did you investigate that?

Comment: Ok I have reboot the serve and now I run it immediately it goes here ReceiverThread(DatagramSocket  receivedSocketConn1) {
      System.out.println("Thread Received"); thereafter I am trying to make a connection on the port it I can connect it. I want to be able to receive multiple data from multipl sources

Comment: Your question keeps changing. I suggest you forget this one and start a new one. Not that there's an answerable question in this last comment. There is no such thing as a 'connection to a port' in UDP.